# Return remote machine last boot time

Tags: vbscript, wmi

I have a script (see below) which returns the last boot time for a list of hostnames read in from a txt file.

However for a machine that isnt reachable it just writes the last machines timestamp.

What do I need to add for a machine thats not reachable to output a blank or 'Unreachable' string?

```
    On Error Resume Next 
Const ForReading = 1 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    ' ===================================================================== 
     'Gets the script to run against each of the computers listed  
     'in the text file path for which should be specified in the syntax below 
    ' ===================================================================== 
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\reboot\machines.txt", ForReading) 
Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Report.txt") 
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream  
    strComputer = objTextFile.Readline 
    ' =============================================================================== 
    ' Code to get the Last Boot Time using LastBootupTime from Win32_Operating System 
    ' =============================================================================== 
Set objWMIService = GetObject _ 
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem") 
For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems 
    dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime 
    dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup) 
    'OutFile.WriteLine "==========================================" 
    OutFile.WriteLine "Computer: " & strComputer 
    OutFile.WriteLine "Last Reboot: " & dtmLastBootupTime 
    dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h", dtmLastBootUpTime, Now)    
    OutFile.WriteLine "System is online since " & dtmSystemUptime & " hours" 
    OutFile.WriteLine "==========================================" 


Next 

    ' ===================================================================== 
    ' End 
    ' ===================================================================== 
Loop 
objTextFile.Close 
 ' =============================================================================== 
 ' Displaying to the user that the script execution is completed 
 ' =============================================================================== 
MsgBox "Script Execution Completed. The Report is saved as Report.txt in the current directory" 
 ' =============================================================================== 
 ' Function to convert UNC time to readable format 
 ' =============================================================================== 
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup) 
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & _ 
         Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) _ 
         & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & _ 
         Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup, _ 
         13, 2)) 
End Function
```

Below is the updated working script

```
    On Error Resume Next
Const ForReading = 1 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

    ' ===================================================================== 
     'Gets the script to run against each of the computers listed  
     'in the text file path for which should be specified in the syntax below 
    ' ===================================================================== 
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\temp\reboot\machines.txt", ForReading) 
Set outfile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("Report.txt") 
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream  
    strComputer = objTextFile.Readline 
    ' =============================================================================== 
    ' Code to get the Last Boot Time using LastBootupTime from Win32_Operating System 
    ' =============================================================================== 
Set objWMIService = GetObject _ 
    ("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        OutFile.WriteLine "==========================================" 
        OutFile.WriteLine "Computer: " & strComputer 
        OutFile.WriteLine "Unreachable"  
        OutFile.WriteLine "==========================================" 
Else
        For Each objOS in colOperatingSystems 
            dtmBootup = objOS.LastBootUpTime 
            dtmLastBootupTime = WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup) 
            OutFile.WriteLine "==========================================" 
            OutFile.WriteLine "Computer: " & strComputer 
            OutFile.WriteLine "Last Reboot: " & dtmLastBootupTime 
            dtmSystemUptime = DateDiff("h", dtmLastBootUpTime, Now)    
            OutFile.WriteLine "==========================================" 
Next    
End if
Err.Clear()




    ' ===================================================================== 
    ' End 
    ' ===================================================================== 


Loop



objTextFile.Close 
 ' =============================================================================== 
 ' Displaying to the user that the script execution is completed 
 ' =============================================================================== 
MsgBox "Script Execution Completed. The Report is saved as Report.txt in the current directory" 

 ' =============================================================================== 

 ' Function to convert UNC time to readable format 
 ' =============================================================================== 
Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmBootup) 
    WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmBootup, 5, 2) & "/" & _ 
         Mid(dtmBootup, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmBootup, 4) _ 
         & " " & Mid (dtmBootup, 9, 2) & ":" & _ 
         Mid(dtmBootup, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmBootup, _ 
         13, 2)) 
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make the call `objWMIService.ExecQuery` and it errors because the host is unreachable your `On Error Resume Next` causes the code to continue execution from the next line and continue to do this until it finds a line that doesn't cause an error.  Your variables will still hold the values from the previous call.  You should test for error after the call using:

```
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
   'An error has occurred so output the "Unreachable" message
Else
   'Call was successful so output last boot time.
End If
```

Comment: I have updated the above with your If statement but it will not run. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say will not run what actually happens?

Comment: After the End If it throws an 'Expected statement error'

Comment: The `Next` should be inside the `End If` and straight after the `End If` you will need `Err.Clear()`